# WFP, NDIS. Размер UDP-дейтаграммы

Tags: c, windows-7

Win7 x64. В общем, пишу фильтр, который перехватывает кое-какие дейтаграммы. Перехватывать нужно лишь пакеты, вес которых больше определенного значения. Оно фиксировано и я хотел бы его задать при указаний conditions в создании фильтра, как номер порта, например, но такого способа не нашел. Я решил выяснять вес при перехвате, но у меня с этим появились проблемы. [Вот](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f7552c1b-b65b-4d34-95d5-26a31bcb16e1/fwpmlayerdatagramdatav4-and-data-length?forum=wfp) здесь описан способ, но он мне не нравится тем, что я подозреваю, что там учитывается лишь вес каждого отдельного IP-пакета, да и не сработал он у меня :) Макросы, которые там используются, обращаются к каким-то левым полям структур *NET_BUFFER_LIST* и *NET_BUFFER*, во всяком случае, так считает мой VS 2013.

В общем, как можно узнать вес дейтаграммы? И действительно ли [эта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562631(v=vs.85).aspx) функция возвращает данные из *N_B_L* **с сохранением порядка**?

Если есть какие-либо идеи, поделитесь, очень буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, видимо, я должен поменьше доверять Intellisense. Эти макросы используют практически везде, в том числе и в примерах MSDN, так что, скорее всего, они должны сработать. Этот вопрос еще в силе:

> И действительно ли [эта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562631(v=vs.85).aspx) функция возвращает данные из NET_BUFFER_LIST с
>   сохранением порядка?